# Занести коллекцию в Session и получить ее от тудаже asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, сессия

У меня есть два метода в контролере. Я хочу передать коллекцию объектов из БД с одного метода в другой.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Testing()
{
    LanguagesRapository engrepos = new LanguagesRapository();
    IEnumerable<English> listWords = engrepos.GetRandom10EnglishWords();
    Session["listWords"] = listWords;
    return View("Testing", listWords.ElementAt(0));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Testing(English eng)
{
    IEnumerable<English> listWords = Session["listWords"] as IEnumerable<English>;

    return View("Testing", listWords.ElementAt(0));
}
```

Пытаюсь реализовать с помощью Session. Но проблема в том, что когда я получаю коллекцию из Session, то в ней оказываются совсем другие данные, будто MVC заново мне вытащил данные непосредственно из самой БД, а не из Сессии. 
Возможно этот подход очень глуп, так что если знает кто,как лучше передать коллекцию из одного метода в другой (с идентичными данными), подскажите как правильно)

Comment: что делает `GetRandom10EnglishWords`? подозреваю все починится если сразу материализовать запрос с помощью. например. `ToList`: `engrepos.GetRandom10EnglishWords().ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ваш Repository возвращает результат вызова свойства контекста, что-то вроде

```
public IEnumerable<English> GetRandom10EnglishWords()
{
    return context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
}
```

это не список объектов, а Query Object - объект, который делает запрос в базу в момент приведения его к списку. Или в момент получения из него конкретного элемента. Так что реальный запрос происходит вот на этой строчке:

```
return View("Testing", listWords.ElementAt(0));
```

Добавьте явное приведение к списку, и запрос начнет происходить в ожидаемый вами момент, а в сессию ляжет его результат.

```
public IEnumerable<English> GetRandom10EnglishWords()
{
    return context.EnglishWords.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10)
                               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: :-D мда, не умею я так красиво расписывать, чтобы в ответ сразу записать

Comment: сейчас не дома, попробую в течении получаса)

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, спасибо. И отдельное спасибо за пояснение как выполняется данная работа, учитывая что ответ был очень простым)